# Running a function before subscribing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I would like to add a form control as soon as the user has selected an option.

**My select function:**

```js
selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
      this.setTechnologies = new Set();
      this.setTechnologies.add(this.techInput.nativeElement.value);
}
```

**Adding a new controller**

```js
this.primaryFormGroup.addControl('tech', new FormControl('', []));
this.primaryFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(inputFields => {
  if (inputFields) {
    inputFields.tech = Array.from(this.setTechnologies);
  }
}
```

My problem is that the line `inputFields.tech = Array.from(this.setTechnologies);` will be executed, **before** the function `selected()` could be run. So in this case the value of `inputFields.tech` is ALWAYS empty.

How can I run the function first?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to add a slight [delay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delay) to `valueChanges`. This ensures that `selected()` function is run before `valueChanges`.

```
this.primaryFormGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
  delay(500)
).subscribe(inputFields => {
  if (inputFields) {
    inputFields.tech = Array.from(this.setTechnologies);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tested it. It's a good solution but it could be quite possible that the user types something into a text field and submits the form by pressing the key enter less than even 100 ms. I think there should be a better solution how to handle this issue.

Comment: @RezaSaadati - I agree that there would be better and more elegant solutions. Can you reproduce this problem on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or similar site and post the link back here? I or someone else can take a look and address the actual issue without having to execute these in order.